# How to run MapReduce Jobs sequentially one after another

Tags: hadoop, scheduling

I am running a single node cluster and handling timeseries data.I have a set of MapReduce jobs run periodically(using Quartz crontrigger) from client application.For example,

```
job1 : runs every 10 min .priority VERY_HIGH
job2 : runs every hour (it takes input from the output of job1).priority HIGH
job3 : runs every day(it takes input from the output of job2).priority NORMAL

.....
```

Everything working fine. But sometimes, multiple jobs can be triggered simultaneously, for example at 00:00 am job1,job2,job3 will be triggered.Even though job priorities set, due to available map slots, these jobs found to be executed parallel. So some input data missed for low priority jobs.

**Brief:** I need to execute strictly in FIFO based on job priority.Means it should be restricted in such a way that only single job runs at a time. i.e, job1 finished, then job2 finished, job3  ..

I don't know how the hadoop schedulers can help me. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing these settings to 1:

mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum    1
mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum 1

If you will limit no of mapper and reducer to 1 then next job has to wait for next mapper to finish. If you look, it is not a good solution.

Using [Oozie](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=https://oozie.apache.org/&ei=C6QFU7TwGoH-rAf0qYGQDA&usg=AFQjCNGwNWyEhhtW2qNohdfUXSPBETX6Mg&sig2=xoTi27qoq3pXt6V77_IVvw&bvm=bv.61725948,d.bmk) workflow engine would best suite your need.

Comment: I agree , what you need is a workflow and oozie is the the way to go

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a new workflow engine called Soop. https://github.com/radixCSgeek/soop it is very lightweight and simple to setup and run using a cron-like syntax. You can specify the job dependencies (including virtual dependencies between jobs) and the DAG engine will make sure to execute them in the right order.